# How to debug a DLL exception in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

There is no error in the code. The build is also successful. This is a problem that happens when I try to debug.

My code

[This is code I wrote in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyQMr.jpg)

The error

[This is the problem I encountered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DL7UJ.jpg)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On the right bottom of your code there is the call stack. You can see in penultimate line there is a call from line 10 of main function that triggers this error further down. This line you receive a string from line 8 which you receive as a argument.

So I assume you are not passing any argument (the image path) to this program when you try execute it as the error further down is related to the string length.